# Where is the AppCode "extract to file" refactoring?

Tags: ios, swift, refactoring, appcode

I pretty sure there used to be a KB shortcut to "extract a class to a separate file".
Am I wrong or where did it go?

I tend to write several classes/structs in the same file when on a roll, and then use refactoring to separate those out in separate files, named according to the class name.

I have just set up a new dev mac and now I cant seem to find that refactoring function.

I'm using:

- Monterey 12.0.1
- Xcode 13.1
- AppCode 2021.2.4 (Classic IntelliJ shortcuts)

[image: Extract class to file missing]

Answer (score 0):

AppCode currently supports Move… (F6) for Objective-C only.

[image: Move declarations to file (existing or new)]